Unable to access the elements of a binding array in a view
I have a
Reminders structure defined as below. I have a main view where I have defined this structure using a state property in a main view, which then calls 2 other views. I have defined this state as binding property in a view. This view reads the array and then displays the values.
struct Reminder: Identifiable, Hashable {
    var id = UUID() 
    var title: String
    var time: Date 
    var rangeStart: Date
    var rangeEnd: Date
    var frequency: Int
    var sound: String 
    var specificTimeSet: Bool
    var remindThroughoutHour: Bool
}

reminderList View:
struct ReminderListView: View {
    @Binding var reminders: [Reminder]
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            if reminders.isEmpty {
                VStack {
                    Text("You’ve no Reminders")
                        .font(.title2)
                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                        .padding()
                    Spacer()
                }
                .navigationTitle("Your Reminders")
            } else {
                List  {
                    ForEach($reminders) { reminder in
                        HStack {
                            Text(reminder.title)
                            Spacer()
                            NavigationLink(destination: CreateReminderView(reminders: $reminders, reminderToEdit: reminder)) {
                                Text("Edit")
                                    .foregroundColor(.blue)
                            }
                            Button(action: {
                                deleteReminder(reminder.wrappedValue)
                            }) {
                                Image(systemName: "trash")
                                    .foregroundColor(.red)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                .navigationTitle("Your Reminders")
            }
        }

    }
}

I get the following error when trying to access reminder.title in the forEach block.
Initializer 'init(_:)' requires that 'Binding<String>' conform to 'StringProtocol'
I'm not sure if this is the right way to access the binding array. How do i fix this pls?
Edit:
I have tried the following prior to posting the question
ForEach($reminders) { $reminder in
                    HStack {
                        Text(reminder.title.wrappedValue)
                        Spacer()
                        NavigationLink(destination: CreateReminderView(reminders: $reminders, reminderToEdit: reminder)) {
                            Text("Edit")
                                .foregroundColor(.blue)
                        }
}

The errors that I get are:
 No exact matches in call to initializer
Candidate expects value of type 'Range<Int>' for parameter #1 (got 'Binding<[Reminder]>') (SwiftUICore.ForEach)
Found candidate with type '(Binding<Array<Reminder>>, @escaping (SectionConfiguration) -> _) -> ForEach<ForEachSectionCollection<_>, SectionConfiguration.ID, _>'
Inferred projection type 'Int' is not a property wrapper'

Try changing it to Text(reminder.title.wrappedValue)

Stop placing Binding inside ForEach and you will be fine.
ForEach($reminders) -> ForEach(reminders)

Here’s a cleaned-up version of your code. You can use it as code example.
struct ReminderListView: View {
    @Binding var reminders: [Reminder]
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            content.navigationTitle("Your Reminders")
        }
    }
    
    @ViewBuilder
    var content: some View {
        if reminders.isEmpty {
            emptyView
        } else {
            listView
        }
    }
    
    var emptyView: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("You’ve no Reminders")
                .font(.title2)
                .foregroundColor(.gray)
                .padding()
            Spacer()
        }
    }
    
    var listView: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(reminders) { reminder in
                NavigationLink(value: reminder.id.description) {
                    HStack {
                        Text(reminder.title)
                        Spacer()
                        Button("", systemImage: "trash") { }.buttonStyle(.plain)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationDestination(for: String.self) { id in
            CreateReminderView(reminders: $reminders, reminderID: id)
        }
    }
}

SwiftUI is easy to start with but quite hard to master. It's best to learn it step by step, or you might create a big mess later on
I suggest learning SwiftUI from Stanford CS193p

Because reminders within ForEach is Binding<Reminder>, try this:
...
ForEach($reminders) { $reminder in //<- put $ here
    HStack {
        Text(reminder.title)
        ...
    }
}


The error you show, is telling you the parameters you use, do not correspond to the parameters you have set for CreateReminderView.
Try this approach using bindings for your properties, as shown in the fully working example code. Tested on iOS 18 and macOS 15, using Xcode 16.2.
Note, NavigationView is deprecated, use NavigationStack instead.
struct ContentView: View {
    
    // --- for testing
    @State private var reminders: [Reminder] = [
        Reminder(title: "title-1", time: Date(), rangeStart: Date(), rangeEnd: Date(), frequency: 1, sound: "", specificTimeSet: false, remindThroughoutHour: false),
        Reminder(title: "title-2", time: Date(), rangeStart: Date(), rangeEnd: Date(), frequency: 1, sound: "", specificTimeSet: false, remindThroughoutHour: false),
        Reminder(title: "title-3", time: Date(), rangeStart: Date(), rangeEnd: Date(), frequency: 1, sound: "", specificTimeSet: false, remindThroughoutHour: false)
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        ReminderListView(reminders: $reminders) // <--- here $
    }
}

struct Reminder: Identifiable, Hashable {
    let id = UUID()  // <--- here
    var title: String
    var time: Date
    var rangeStart: Date
    var rangeEnd: Date
    var frequency: Int
    var sound: String
    var specificTimeSet: Bool
    var remindThroughoutHour: Bool
}

struct ReminderListView: View {
    @Binding var reminders: [Reminder]
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {   // <--- here
            if reminders.isEmpty {
                VStack {
                    Text("You’ve no Reminders")
                        .font(.title2)
                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                        .padding()
                    Spacer()
                }
                .navigationTitle("Your Reminders")
            } else {
                List {
                    ForEach($reminders) { $reminder in  // <--- here $
                        HStack {
                            Text(reminder.title)  // <--- here
                            Spacer()
                            NavigationLink(destination: CreateReminderView(reminders: $reminders, reminderToEdit: $reminder)) {  // <--- here $
                                Text("Edit").foregroundColor(.blue)
                            }
                            Button(action: {
                                  deleteReminder(reminder)  // <--- here
                            }) {
                                Image(systemName: "trash").foregroundColor(.red)
                            }
                            .padding(.horizontal, 20)
                            .buttonStyle(.bordered)
                        }
                    }
                }
                .navigationTitle("Your Reminders")
            }
        }
    }
    
    func deleteReminder(_ reminder: Reminder) {  // <--- here
        if let index = reminders.firstIndex(of: reminder) {
            reminders.remove(at: index)
        }
    }
}

struct CreateReminderView: View {
    @Binding var reminders: [Reminder] // <--- if you really need it
    @Binding var reminderToEdit: Reminder
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField("Title", text: $reminderToEdit.title) // <--- for testing
            .border(.blue)
    }
}

